# Logging out doesn't log out from data.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, data-explorer, logout

Logging out [says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu0X6.jpg) it logs out from stackexchange.com but that's incorrect as it doesn't log out from data.stackexchange.com.

Tested on Chrome with Android on a Galaxy S23.

Comment: It's using totally different mechanism, it's also not listed in the network accounts. The logout logs out only from your network accounts. (Guess my point is that it's not a bug, and impossible to implement as feature request too)

Comment: The bug here isn't that it isn't logging you out of Data Explorer, but rather that it misleadingly implies that it logs you out of there when it doesn't.

Comment: The first bug is that it didn't log you in either, so I'm not sure where we should go with this.

Comment: @Sonic well ideally, SEDE will be on its own domain, then not be listed there. It is **not** a Stack Exchange site, it's an external project, that is hosted and maintained by Stack Exchange. (Pretty much same as [traducir](https://traducir.win/))